# imagecreatetruecolor() not working in symfony but works fine if run as a php script

Tags: php, symfony

The class which contains the method is as follows:

```
<?php
   class renderText {
      function text_to_image( $text, $width, $height, $image_file ) {
         $fonts_dir = 'path/to/directory/in/which/SreeKrushnadevaraya.ttf/is/located/';
         $ret = mb_language('uni');
         mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
         header('Content-type: image/gif');
         $font = $fonts_dir.'SreeKrushnadevaraya.ttf';
         error_log("=before imagecrttrucolour",3,'path/to/frontend_dev.log');
         $im = imagecreatetruecolor( $width, $height );
         error_log("=after imagecrttrucolour",3,'path/to/frontend_dev.log');
         $white = imagecolorallocate( $im, 255, 255, 255 );
         $black = imagecolorallocate( $im, 0, 0, 0 );
         imagefilledrectangle( $im, 0, 0, $width, $height, $white );
         imagettftext( $im, 10, 0,10 ,30, $black, $font, $text );
         $image_file = '/tmp/'.date('YmdHis').$width.$height.'.gif';
         imagegif( $im, $image_file );
         imagedestroy( $im );
         return $image_file;
      }
   }
?>
```

The following code is added in symfony as well as the local script. It works fine in the local script but fails in symfony:

```
// Set the enviroment variable for GD
putenv('GDFONTPATH=' . realpath('path/to/directory/in/which/SreeKrushnadevaraya.ttf/is/located/'));

// Name the font to be used (note the lack of the .ttf extension)
$font = 'SreeKrushnadevaraya';
```

The method is called thus:

```
$image_file = '/tmp/'.date('YmdHis').'260'.'x'.'32.gif';
 $rendered_text = renderText::text_to_image($this->getRequestParameter('caption_unicode'), 240, 32, $image_file);
```

php Version : PHP 5.3.6

symfony version 1.0.22

Comment: You have to tell more than "does not work". Also show as the symfony specific part.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have **two versions of PHP** installed:

- **the Apache extension** used when running it via Symfony
- and **the PHP cli** used when you run scripts

And each version has it's own `php.ini` configuration file. You probably haven't loaded the extension or misconfigured it in the Apache configuration file.

You can find out the location of the Apache php.ini configuration file when executing phpinfo(). (In the Symfony toolbar for example)